# Create A Folder and Switch to Folder while Using Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I hope that everyone is doing well. I have been attempting to do my own thing and research a way to do this for the past two or three days, but I have had no luck. Is there a way for me to create a directory after some information is inputted by the user and change to that directory to upload the files there? What I am trying to do is upload files to a folder that will be named based on the information put in by the user before multer uploads the file. If there is an alternative way, I am open to advice. My code below and I have uploaded my react js code just incase.

Node JS:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../config/db');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const SqlDbStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const passport = require('passport');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
//----------------------------------------- BEGINNING OF PASSPORT MIDDLEWARE AND SETUP ---------------------------------------------------
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(session({
    key: 'session_cookie_name',
    secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
    store: new SqlDbStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: '**************',
    database: '**************',
    }),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie:{
        maxAge:1000*60*60*24,
        secure: false
    }
}));
const multerDestination = './routes/Images/';
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, files, cb) {
    cb(null, multerDestination);
  },
  filename: function (req, files, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + files.originalname );
  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('files');
//----------------------------------------- END OF PASSPORT MIDDLEWARE AND SETUP ---------------------------------------------------
router.post('/properties_upload', (req, res) => {
  const address = req.body.addressLine;
  const address2 = req.body.addressLine2;
  const city = req.body.city;
  const state = req.body.state;
  const addressZipCode = req.body.addressZipCode;
  const mlsID = req.body.mlsID;
  const rentalID = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000;
  var directory;

  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        return res.status(500).json(err)
    } else if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json(err)
    }

    for (const file of req.files) {
      directory = path.dirname(file.path);
    }

    console.log('File path: ' + directory);
    return res.status(200).send(req.files);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

React JS:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './Properties_Upload.css';
import Navbar from '../../../Components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Footer from '../../../Components/Footer/Footer';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Properties_Upload() {
    const [addressLine, setAddressLine] = useState('');
    const [addressLine2, setAddressLine2] = useState('');
    const [addressCity, setAddressCity] = useState('');
    const [addressState, setAddressState] = useState('');
    const [addressZipCode, setAddressZipCode] = useState('');
    const [mlsID, setMLSID] = useState('');
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState('');
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    const propertyInfoHandler = () => {
        const url = 'http://localhost:3001/property/properties_upload';
        const data = new FormData() 

        for (var x = 0; x < selectedFile.length; x++) {
            data.append('files', selectedFile[x]);
        }

        Axios.post(url, data, {
            addressLine: addressLine,
            addressLine2: addressLine2,
            addressCity: addressCity,
            addressState: addressState,
            addressZipCode: addressZipCode,
            mlsID: mlsID
        })
        .then((response) => {
            navigate('/properties');
            if (response.data.errorMessage){
                setErrorMessage(response.data.message);
            }
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <div className='propertiesUploadBody'>
                <h1>Properties Upload</h1>
                <div className='propertyInfoFormBody'>
                    <h1>Property Information</h1>
                    <p className='addressLine'> *Property address: <input name='addressLine' placeholder='Address' required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setAddressLine(e.target.value)} /> </p>
                    <p className='addressLine2'> Apartment/Suite/Unit: <input name='addressLine2' placeholder='Apartment/Suite/Unit' autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setAddressLine2(e.target.value)} /> </p>
                    <p className='addressCity'> *Property city: <input name='addressCity' placeholder='City' required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setAddressCity(e.target.value)} /> </p>
                    <p className='addressState'> *Property state: <input name='addressState' placeholder='State' maxLength={2} required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setAddressState(e.target.value)} /> </p>
                    <p className='addressZipCode'> *Property zip code: <input type='number' name='addressZipCode' placeholder='Zip Code' required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setAddressZipCode(e.target.value)} /> </p>
                    <p className='propertyMLSID'> MLS ID: <input type='number' name='propertyMLSID' placeholder='MLS ID' required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setMLSID(e.target.value)} /></p>
                </div>
                <div className='propertyFileFormBody'>
                    <h1>Property Image Upload</h1>
                    <p> Upload Images of the property.</p>
                    <input className='uploadFiles' type='file' name='file' multiple required onChange={(e) => setSelectedFile(e.target.files)} />
                </div>
                <h2>{errorMessage}</h2>
                <button className='uploadButton' onClick={propertyInfoHandler}>Upload Property</button>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: You write "based on the information put in by the user before multer uploads the file". Can you be more precise where that information is kept? Does it come with the same request? Also, the third parameter of your `Axios.post` is wrong, you must append the properties `addressLine`, ... to the `data` object.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen, so when the address is passed, I want to make a sub folder in images titled what the address is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform asynchronous file system operations before invoking the callback `cb` in the `destination` function.

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, files, cb) {
    var addressLine = req.body.addressLine;
    var multerDestination;
    // Decide what multerDestination should be based on addressLine or other user info.
    fs.mkdir(multerDestination, function(err) {
      if (err && err.code !== "EEXIST") cb(err);
      else cb(multerDestination);
    }
  },
  filename: ...
});
```

If you want to evaluate additional form fields beside the uploaded files (like the `addressLine`), they must come *before* the files when you construct the `FormData`:

```js
const data = new FormData();
data.append('addressLine', addressLine);
...
for (var x = 0; x < selectedFile.length; x++) {
  data.append('files', selectedFile[x]);
}
Axios.post(url, data).then(...);
```

Otherwise, `req.body` will not yet be filled when the `destination` function is executed.

Comment: So currently, the files are uploaded to a folder called "Images" via multer. I want the backend to make a folder with the address line as the name of the folder and then upload images to that folder. Makes sense? And thank you for the extra info, I made the changes.